# JQuery in a anonymous invoking function: Why?

Tags: jquery

I've just been following some tutorials on listeners for JQuery.

In the tutorial, they always recommend to put all JQuery script code in an anonymous invoking javascript function with no arguments.

Is there a reason for this? The listeners work when outside the anonymous function body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
})();
```

It's because then the functions you declare within that function don't become globals. The global namespace is crowded enough, and there's rarely any reason to add to it.

For instance, if you did this:

```
<script>
function foo() {
    // ...do something useful...
}

// Use foo
foo(); // or `$("some selector").click(foo);`, etc.
</script>
```

...you'd create a global called `foo`. But if you do this:

```
<script>
(function() {
    function foo() {
        // ...do something useful...
    }

    // Use foo
    foo(); // or `$("some selector").click(foo);`, etc.
})();
</script>
```

...you don't.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
}
```

short version:

```
$(function() {
});
```

This function, given that jquery is referenced, will trigger when your dom is ready.
must not be mixed with the anonymous self invoking:

```
(function() {
})();
```

The last one has nothing to do with jquery

Answer (score -1):

What are you saying? Can you be a bit more clear?

Are you referring to something like this

```
$(".some-class").bind("click hover", function(){
    // Do something
});
```

If you are referring to this, then this might help

```
Syntax

bind(eventType, data, listener)
```

here eventType (strings) are events like "click", "hover" etc
listener(function) is the code that has to be executed as soon as the eventType is fired.

Hence the function is run as soon as the event has been fired regardless of name.